# Setting Cache-Control in IIS

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-7.5, cache-control

I am trying to set Cache-Control to `no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private` in the HTTP Response Headers section in IIS Manager (v7.5). If I add a new custom HTTP Response Header and paste above string in there, I am getting the following output inspecting the website:

`Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private`

How come the private value is set twice? I guess it is set somewhere within ISS already, since it shows `Cache-Control: private` even if I remove my custom HTTP Request Header.

This leaves me with the following two questions:

1. What is the right way of setting the HTTP Response Header
   `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private`
   site-wide?
2. What would be the caveat of having set `Cache-Control: no-cache,
   no-store, must-revalidate, private` site-wide?

I found a good [summary on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers) already but nothing specific to setting the HTTP Response Header for Cache-Control site-wide within IIS.

I am running a classic asp application. Could it be that the second private attribute is set there? Any starting point where I could look?

Thank you very much for you help :-)